# How to subset within a for-loop using lists

Tags: r, subset

I'm going to apologize in advance because this is going to be tricky to give example data for.

Basically, I need to subset a portion of all my (very large) .csv files. I need columns 102:110 (all 1278 rows). I read in all the .csv files into a list (PsychoPy). I want to create a new list with all the new, subsetted .csv files (PsychoPy2). I have tried the following:

```
PsychoPy2 <- list()
for(i in 1:31){
  PsychoPy2[[i]] <- (PsychoPy[[i]][,102:110])
}
```

I keep getting the following error: `` Error in `[.data.frame`(PsychoPy[[i]], 1:1278, 102:110) :  undefined columns selected ``

I've tried but the files are too large to upload here.

Comment: Can you post a more substantive amount of your code, perhaps the entire for loop?   You could also try to present a reproducible example that returns the same error, maybe with simulated data

Answer (score 0):

Hello fellow psychophysicist!

*Before posting my initial response I wondered if the parentheses within your for loop might be causing the problem. This appears to work when I test it (if I've understood your construction of the PsychoPy list):*

```
for(i in 1:31){
  PsychoPy2[[i]] <- PsychoPy[[i]][,102:110]
}
```

*Failing that, my first thought was a different approach:*

If I understand/infer correctly from your example, you have 31 .csv files from which you want to create list of 31 objects, each corresponding to [,102:110] of the table from each file.

To do that I would use a loop when reading in each file to read the data file, copy the desired cells into a blank list, and repeat. Is there a reason behind not doing this? (I've not got much experience with very large .csv files so I wonder if 31 calls to read.csv() for them might be prohibitive/long) I myself would try the following:

```
CSVlocation='C:/YourDataFolder' #file path to folder containing your csv files
filelist=list.files(path=CSVlocation, pattern='*.csv') #list names of your CSV files

PsychoPy2=list() #Create an empty list to add to
for(i in 1:31){ 
  
  filepath=file.path(CSVlocation, filelist[i]) #create file path to load
  data<-read.csv(filepath) #load the csv file into 
  
  PsychoPy2[[i]]<-data[,102:110]
  }
```

I believe that should work, or may take some tinkering (not had a chance to test it with some dummy files myself)

Answer (score 0):

You loop code looks good (I've tested with some sample data), although you can easily achieve the expected output with `PsychoPy2 <- lapply(PsychoPy, "[", 102:110)`.

I belive that some of your csv files don't have columns from 102 to 110.
Please check it with:

```r
target_dir <- "directory_with_csv_files"
files <- list.files(target_dir, "csv$", full.names = T)
ncol_files <- sapply(files, function(file) ncol(read.csv(file)))
```

This will return the number of columns per csv file. Will can further check if `all(ncol_files >= 110)` returns `TRUE`. If not, then you must check in `ncol_files` which of them has fewer columns.